# C++ Builder 10.4, FMX: Form TabOrder problem

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality to switch between control fields seems to be not working with C++ Builder 10.4 (with patch 1, 2 and 3), if a form control which contains some taborder fields, gets another parent form control programmaticly.

This can be reproduced very easily by creating a Multi-Device Application, with just 2 `TLayout`-controls and 2 `TEdit`-controls on a form:

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new Multi-Device Application, Blank Application. This will create a `Unit1` with a blank form.
- For the generated `Unit1`, just drop a `TLayout` from the Palette to the form and resize this to match almost the left half of the form.
- Drop a second `TLayout` control on the form (Layout2) and resize this layout to match the right half of the form.
- Drop 2 `TEdit` control fields on Layout1 (Edit1 and Edit2).
- For Layout1, set the `TabOrder` property to 0, and make sure the property `TabStop` is set to `True`.
- For Layout2, set the `TabOrder` property to 1, and make sure the property `TabStop` is set to `True`.
- For Edit1, set the `TabOrder` property to 0, make sure the property `TabStop` is set to `True`, and set text to "edit1".
- For Edit2, set the `TabOrder` property to 1, make sure the property `TabStop` is set to `True`, and set text to "edit2".
- Build and run the project: The form with 2 edit fields appears and with <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can switch between the fields. This is OK! If the value of the `Layout1` property `TabOrder` is kept to be -1, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> is also working, but only after selecting 1 of the edit fields with a mouse-click.
- Now, in the constructor of `TForm1` program `Layout2` as the parent of `Layout1`:

```cpp
    #include "Unit1.h"
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #pragma package(smart_init)
    #pragma resource "*.fmx"
    TForm1 *Form1;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
    {
        Layout1->Parent = Layout2;
    }
```

- Build and run the project again. The position of the edit fields on the form is now changed to the right as expected. But there the <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality is gone!

Why? If the same steps are executed in C++ Builder 10.2, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality keeps working after setting the parent of `Layout1` to `Layout2`.

Content of Unit1.fmx, as requested by "Schneider Infosystems Ltd":

```
    object Form1: TForm1
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form1'
      ClientHeight = 480
      ClientWidth = 640
      FormFactor.Width = 320
      FormFactor.Height = 480
      FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
      OnShow = FormShow
      DesignerMasterStyle = 0
      object Layout1: TLayout
        Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 305.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 409.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        object Edit1: TEdit
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 0
          Text = 'edit1'
          Position.X = 64.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 72.000000000000000000
        end
        object Edit2: TEdit
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 1
          Text = 'edit2'
          Position.X = 64.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 112.000000000000000000
        end
      end
      object Layout2: TLayout
        Position.X = 328.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 305.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 409.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 1
      end
    end
```

Comment: It works fine for me, but I'm on 10.3.3  That's probably it ...

Comment: OK, thank you. It is good to know it works in other versions. That confirms it is a bug in 10.4 in my opinion.

Comment: In Delphi 10.4.0, this issue is not reproducible. Can you show the unit1.fmx file too?

Comment: See above " Schneider Infosystems Ltd". But I was told there is a new version 10.4.1 , I was not aware of... Since 02-sep-2020 with a patch 1. I thought I had installed the latest C++Builder, and the IDE mentions it is up-to-date with patch 1, 2 and 3. But apperently not. So, I will install this 10.4.1 version of RadStudio, test again, and report back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!
It works after installing "C++ Builder 10.4.1" !
So, it was a bug in 10.4.

I have to do a lot more actions to build and test all existing software I care about, but I am happy that the TAB-key functionallity seems to be solved! :)

I had to do a complete deïnstall and install of RadStudio. Also third party software has to be integrated again in the IDE. A lot of work. I keep wondering why this was necessary, and could not be solved with patch updates with "GetIt" in version 10.4.